# C++ RPG Error: data member initializer is not allowed

Tags: c++

this has already been posted several times, but none of the times have answered my case. Please help me with my 'error: data member initializer is not allowed' which appears under the equals signs. Here's the code with the problem in it.

```
//Player.cpp :Contains information about the player
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Main.cpp"
using namespace std;

void Player()
{
struct Player {
int Charma = 0;
unsigned int Hunger = 10;
unsigned int Energy = 50;
unsigned int Health = 100;
};
enum Race {
UNKNOWN,
DEAD,
HUMAN,
ORC,
GOBLIN,
ELF,
LIZARD,
CAT,
VAMPIRE,
WEREWOLF,
SNK
};
}
```

Comment: Why are you declaring a `struct` inside a function?  Move it out, and change the name of either the function or class to avoid name conflicts and confusion.

Comment: The tag [rpg] should not be here IMO. The game category of the final idea doesn't describe the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are initializing the variables when you are declaring a `struct`. This is not allowed. Instead, move the initialization into the constructor of the struct.

However that is not the only error in your code. You are defining the `struct` inside of the `Player` function (which should be the constructor). You need to switch those, so that you have the `Player` function inside of the `Player` struct. This way the struct will have a constructor where you can initialize the values. Another thing, don't `#include` .cpp files. It's a bad practice.

Your code should be something like this:

```
struct Player {
int Charma;
unsigned int Hunger;
unsigned int Energy;
unsigned int Health;

   Player() : Charma(0), Hunger(10), Energy(50), Health(100)
   {
      // do other constructor stuff here
   }
};
```

Comment: With a new enough version of C++ you can initialize member variables when you declare a struct, just like you can with a class.

Answer (score 0):

In another approach of idea, if you are planning on doing some mecanics inside `Player`, you may move the declaration inside a real `class`. You will then be able to scale your project a little more easily. Something like this:

**Header**

```
// #include "Item.h"

typedef enum RaceDef {
    UNKNOWN,
    DEAD,
    HUMAN,
    ORC,
    GOBLIN,
    ELF,
    LIZARD,
    CAT,
    VAMPIRE,
    WEREWOLF,
    SNK
} PlayerRace;

class Player {
public:
   Player(unsigned int Charma=0,
          unsigned int Hunger=10,
          unsigned int Energy=50,
          unsigned int Health=100,
          PlayerRace Race=HUMAN);

   void attack(Player);
   void slap(Player);
   //void equipItem(Item);
   void exercise(unsigned int duration);
   void die();
   void etc();

private:
   unsigned int m_Charma;
   unsigned int m_Hunger;
   unsigned int m_Energy;
   unsigned int m_Health;
   unsigned PlayerRace m_Race;

   Race m_Race;
};
```

**CPP**

```
Player::Player(unsigned int Charma,
               unsigned int Hunger,
               unsigned int Energy,
               unsigned int Health,
               PlayerRace Race):
m_Charma(Charma),
m_Hunger(Hunger),
m_Energy(Energy),
m_Health(Health),
m_Race(Race) {
    //constructor code goes here
    //e.g. if player starts with a random item :
    //   Item randomItem = ItemUtils.getRandomItem();
    //   equipItem(randomItem);
}
```

I hope this helps, and good luck :)